# How to send file name to my gmail with PHP and HTML form?

Tags: php, html, forms, sendmail

I would like if someone upload a file gets the name of the file to my gmail.For example, I would like you to email arrives "FileName: background.jpg"

PHP code:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
      $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
      $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
      $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
      $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
      $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
      for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
         if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "uploads/".$name_array[$i])){
            header("Location:");
         }
      }
   }
?>
```

I've tried to like this:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
      $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
      $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
      $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
      $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
      $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
      $za = "mygmail@gmail.com";
      $od  = "Od: " . $Email . "\r\n";
      $info .= "FileName:" .$name_array. "\r\n";
         for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
           if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "uploads/".$name_array[$i])){
              header("Location:");
              mail($za, $od, $info);
           }
        }
    }
?>
```

But I just received in the mail "FileName: array".

HTML code:

```
<form class="contact_form" action="../assets/php/postavi_oglas.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Izaberite fotografije:</label>
    <input class="contact_area" type="file" name="file_array[]">
    <input class="contact_area" type="file" name="file_array[]">
    <input class="contact_area" type="file" name="file_array[]">
    <input class="contact_area" type="file" name="file_array[]">
    <input class="contact_area" type="file" name="file_array[]">
    <input class="btn btn-theme" type="submit" value="Posalji Fotografije">  
</form>
```

Comment: put this inside you for loop $info .= "FileName:" .$name_array[$i]. "\r\n"; it is a array and need to be in the loop

Comment: Yes, but I was this time only arrived "FileName:", not we arrived file name (for example: "FileName: Background.jpg")..

Comment: let me edit the answer underneath then you try again it might be the [ ] that causes it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it says array because it is array and need to be in the loop

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "uploads/".$name_array[$i])){
    // a array      
     $fname=$name_array[$i];
     $info= "FileName:" .$fname. "\r\n";     
     header("Location:");
     mail($za, $od, $info);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You got array here, because you send one in your mail. Just use it like code below and send just on email instead of one email by file. I you like this behavior more.

```
 $info = ''; 

 for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "uploads/".$name_array[$i])){
       $info .= 'Filename '.$i.': '.$name_array[$i]. "\r\n";
    }
 }

 mail($za, $od, $info);
 header("Location:");
```